# When will spring fix abstract mapping on couchbase reactive

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

Is there any solution how to use super type (abstract class) in spring boot starter data couchbase reactive ?
My idea is to have super type and save this super type into couchabse bucket, and read from it.
Writing is working perfectly, but on read I got exception:

**org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.entities.Report]: Class is abstract**

Classes are implemented like:
Report:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "documentType"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestReport::class, name = TestReport.DOCUMENT_TYPE),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Test2Report::class, name = Test2Report.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
)

@Document
abstract class Report : SyncDocument {

    var inspectorId: String = ""
    var reportNumber: String = ""
    var reportDate: Long = 0

    constructor() : super(null) {}
}
```

TestReport:

```
@Document
@TypeAlias(TestReport.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
class TestReport : Report {
    companion object {
        const val DOCUMENT_TYPE: String = "TestReport"
    }

    var string3: String = ""

    constructor() : super() {}
}
```

Test2Report:

```
@Document
@TypeAlias(Test2Report.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
class Test2Report : Report {
    companion object {
        const val DOCUMENT_TYPE: String = "Test2Report"
    }

    var string2: String = ""

    constructor() : super() {}
}
```

I have implemented code in this way on other android project where ReactiveCrudRepository is not used, and works perfectly. Now I want to use same schema on ReactiveCrudRepository.

Thank you on any sugestions :D

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see the complete stack trace and to know what version you are using.

In Java, you could simply make Report not Abstract. Does that not work in Android?

Thanks,

- Mike

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege to turn this into a comment and delete this seemingly non-answering answer post.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1315 which is in 4.3.2 that was released today.